# Librarian checkout error prevents from sync

Tags: perforce

P4 calls "Librarian checkout" issues on folders (and files in it) that are not present in the depot tree BUT present on the perforce server - in from of empty folders.
If I try to obliterate (files or files with changelist) with p4 obliterate it tells me "No records to delete", when I'm using the Administration client it just cannot locate those when using obliterate option.

This in general prevents me from syncing with new workspaces, as it seems like upon syncing p4 fails to sync the files that were copied from other streams and points to revisions that are not there.

Example:
Librarian checkout D:\streamdepot/STREAM_NAME/unity/PROJECT_X/assets/objects/vehicles/materials/e_smallcorridor_01_cords_d.mat failed.
open for read: D:\streamdepot/STREAM_NAME/unity/PROJECT_X/assets/objects/vehicles/materials/e_smallcorridor_01_cords_d.mat,d\1.9789.gz: The system cannot find the file specified.

STREAM_NAME doesn't exists, and revision 9789 doesn't exist in history.

Thanks for any help in that matter!

Comment: That's bad. Would recommend contacting Perforce Support.

Comment: You'll need to restore backups of those archive files (the ones referenced in the error messages) if you have them.

Comment: Do you have the solution for this, instead of contacting perforce support? Looking few references http://www.pandaros.com/blog/2016/12/15/perforce-librarian-checkout-path-to-file-failed/ it looks like it solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the top result for searching the error even 7 years later:
I ran into this when setting up perforce with Unreal Engine 5,

MY SOLUTION: The issue ended up being that I had not created my Typemap yet and so the host was trying to upload .uasset without them being stated in the typemap - so when the receiver tried to download my files any .uasset files failed to be gathered because the uploading computer couldnt write them correctly to the perforce server

Make sure your typemaps are correct!